# full page background image causes scroll bar

Tags: scroll

I'm having trouble with an issue on a site -

http://www.Afrifacti.com

I checked for an answer and someone mentioned turning off #footer-container { height: 100%; }, but that leaves an empty box below. http://cl.ly/Tv2I

Basically, I want the image to fill the screen as it does now, but without the scroll bar or empty box below.

However, the scroll bar should reappear if the browser height is shrunk beyond the footer buttons 'about credits join'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add at body element (base.css line 12) the style: `position:fixed` and you done.